# Adding the total number from a specific custom field of all channel entries

Tags: channel, custom-fields

I am wondering if the following is possible to do within ExpressionEngine:

On the front end of the site, I would like ExpressionEngine to search a particular custom field within a particular channel, and add all of those numbers together to come up with a sum total. So for example...I have a channel named "Invoices" and within that channel, I have a custom field named "Monthly Total" which only has numbers and a decimal (ie. 15.25). On the front end of the website, I would like to display the sum total of custom field named "Monthly Total" for every single entry in that channel. So essentially, this front end section would automatically update when a new channel entry is created or deleted.

I hope that made sense, can this be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code please?  What have you tried?  I don't think you can do this with /just/ vanilla EE.  You would need to handle the the math with an add-on or php or javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I was able to figure things out though. I had to use the "Tally" addon and it accomplished the task. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the "Tally" addon found here https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tally.  It works like a charm.